# Methods for incremental score calculations

Tags: optaplanner

can someone explain the purpose of the methods that need to be implemented for incremental score calculation? I understand all the after... methods, but why should I adjust the score before an entity is added, removed or a variable is changed (beforeEntityAdded, beforeVariableChanged, beforeEntityRemoved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this image from the 6.0.0.Final docs:

[image]

Also see the section "incremental score calculation" (which also explains why this is so much faster than SimpleScoreCalculator). Look at the example implementations. You'll see that `beforeVariableChanged()` is needed to retract the violated constraint matches that no longer match.

In the diagram above, the ChangeMove needs to get `+1` because AB no longer match during the `beforeVariableChanged()` method and `-1` becaues AC now match during the `afterVariableChanged` method.